# Show that eigenvalue of A is singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a *normal eigenvector* of $A \in M_n$ with associated 
 eigenvalue $λ$,  show that  $|λ|$ is a *singular value* of $A$.

Comment: What is $C_n,$ and where do you use $x$?

Comment: @Chickenmancer Sorry, I fix it.

Comment: What is a "normal eigenvector"? If it means joint eigenvector of $A$ and $A^*$ then this is obvious from the definition of singular values as the eigenvalues of $\sqrt{A^*A}$.

Comment: @Conifold Can you prove it formally please?

Comment: Hint: a joint eigenvector is also an eigenvector of $A^*A$. Find the corresponding eigenvalue.